# How to query all users from database and it's related data?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-4

Returning data from any table is simply easy.
Let's say :

- I want to retrieve the data from my `user` table as json format.
- I can just simply do this. `return Response::json(User::all());`

But what if, I want to return the data from my users table `and` **ALL** of it's `related` data as json format.

How do I do that ? 
Is there any Laravel mechanism that help me do that ? 
Is there any php functions that does this trick ?

If anyone of you have any experience with this, and like to share, please feel free.

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: You can do a JOIN query and then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load the relationships using the `with()` method:

```
return Response::json(User::with('address', 'phones')->get());
```

However, you have to manually specify all the relations (i.e. you have to specify 'address' and 'phones').  As far as I know, there is no built in way to programmatically determine the relationships.

### Edit

You should be able to either chain `with()` calls, or specify all the relations in one `with()` call. The following statements should all be equivalent:

```
// chaining with statements
return Response::json(User::with('address')->with('phones')->get());

// passing all relationships as strings
return Response::json(User::with('address', 'phones')->get());

// passing in array of all relationships
return Response::json(User::with(array('address', 'phones'))->get());
```

Also, the name of the relationship to pass in is the name of the function that defines the relationship. So, if you had the following class:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function distributor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Distributor');
    }

    public function download()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Download');
    }

    public function log()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Log');
    }
}
```

Your call would look like:

```
return Response::json(User::with('distributor', 'download', 'log')->get());
```

Comment: 1- I replace `all()` with `get()` `return Response::json(User::with('address', 'phones')->get());` because we can not do that we `all()` function.

Comment: 2- For some reason, within the `with` function, it won't let me chain another relation. It work when I did this `return Response::json(User::with('Distributor')->get());`

Comment: 3- It's doesn't work when I do this `return Response::json(User::with('Distributor','Download','Log')->get());`

Comment: @iggy I have updated the answer in response to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
Users::with("userinfo")->get()->toJson();
```

`toJson()` Give JSON Response.